# How to detect if Windows 8 device is on WiFi/LAN or 3G Internet connection?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there a way how to detect if current Windows 8 device is using **Internet from WiFi/LAN or from 3G connection**? We have to provide different image and video quality in our app based on the network speed.

I've so far only checked the **ConnectionCost** and **NetworkAdapter** API, but I'm not sure, if this is what I want:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700381.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NetworkInformation` ,`ConnectionCost` and the other network APIs exist to help with your scenario.  Is it missing some functionality that you need for your specific app?

Kraig Brockschmidt has a nice [implementation of a network connectivity test on his blog](http://kraigbrockschmidt.com/blog/?p=739) that might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I've ended with "if (profile.GetConnectionCost() == NetworkCostType.Unrestricted) { // use high quality data } else { // use reduced quality data } and it works fine when using WiFi/LAN or 3G Internet.

Answer (score 8):

You can find network type with `NetworkAdapter` class. It has property [IanaInterfaceType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.connectivity.networkadapter.ianainterfacetype.aspx). To check all the IANA interface, go [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ianaiftype-mib/ianaiftype-mib)

```
var profile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
var interfaceType = profile.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType;

// 71 is WiFi & 6 is Ethernet(LAN)
if (interfaceType == 71 || interfaceType == 6) 
{
  //TODO:
}
// 243 & 244 is 3G/Mobile
else if (interfaceType == 243 || interfaceType == 244)
{
  //TODO:
}
```